# Javascript loop only works if I do an alert()

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a javascript spinning wheel but I can only get it to run by putting an alert() in the while method, seen below (and then on Chrome clicking to ignore successive messages). Any help or an explanation of what is happening would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colors = ["#000000", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF", "#FFFFFF"];
    var arc = Math.PI / 2;
    var ctx;
    var startAngle = 0;

    function drawWheel(startAngle) {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("wheel");
        if (canvas.getContext) { // Checks for browser support
            var outerRadius = 200,
                    innerRadius = 1;

            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

            ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;

            for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // change to support size of wheel
                var angle = startAngle + i * arc;
                ctx.fillStyle = colors[i];

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(250, 250, outerRadius, angle, angle + arc, false);
                ctx.arc(250, 250, innerRadius, angle + arc, angle, true);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.fill();
            }
        }
    }

    function clearWheel() {
        var canvas = document.getElementById("wheel");
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
    }

    var i = 0;

    while (i<=500) {
        // alert(i);
        drawWheel(i);
        i++;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would put a breakpoint in the while loop to ensure that the code is being run.
The alert should not have any impact on the code.

Attaching a debugger may also expose a suppressed error message that you're not seeing when running this in normal mode.